# Puzzle: The number of quadratic equations which are unchanged by squaring their roots is

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics

My friend asked me this puzzle:

> The number of quadratic equations which are unchanged by squaring their roots is

My answer is: 3

$x^2-(\alpha+\beta)x +\alpha\beta = 0$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the roots.

case 1: 
$\alpha$ = 0
$\beta$ = 0

case 2: $\alpha$ = 1
$\beta$ =1

case 3:$\alpha$ = 0
$\beta$ = 1

But my friend says answer is 4. How come?

Answer (score 15):

Your approach is good; you've just overlooked a solution. As you implied, we must have

$$\alpha^2+\beta^2=\alpha+\beta$$

and

$$\alpha^2\beta^2=\alpha\beta\;.$$

The second equation is fulfilled if at least one root is $0$; those are your cases $1$ and $3$. It's also fulfilled if $\alpha\beta=1$. Substituting that into the first equation yields

$$\alpha^2+\frac1{\alpha^2}=\alpha+\frac1\alpha\;,\\
\alpha^4-\alpha^3-\alpha+1=0\;.$$

One solution is $\alpha=1$; that corresponds to your case $2$. Dividing through by $\alpha-1$ yields

$$\alpha^3-1=0\;.$$

This again has $\alpha=1$ as a solution, but also $\alpha=\exp(2\pi\mathrm i/3)$ and $\alpha=\exp(2\pi\mathrm i/3)^2$. These two together yield the fourth solution you were missing.

Comment: One can also arrive at the fourth pair in a less systematic fashion by noting that any solution to $\alpha^2 = \beta$ and $\beta^2 = \alpha$ would also solve the equation. Joriki's answer, however, also tells you that there isn't more than 4 quadratic polynomials with this property.

Comment: Because they are roots of unity and Euler's formula is nice for those. Alternatively, some like me may appreciate the puzzle better when the answer is stated equivalently as $\alpha = i\sqrt{3}/2-1/2$ and $\alpha = -i\sqrt{3}/2-1/2$.

Comment: @joriki: does the question mean an equation, cutting the x axis at two roots, where if the roots are squared, they don't change, and so neither the points where it meets the x axis nor the shape of the graph change?

Comment: @HarryHolmes: No – it doesn't say "if the roots are squared, they don't change" – in fact, the three answers that are listed in the question are precisely the ones where the roots don't change if they're squared – but the question doesn't require the roots to be unchanged, only the equation. So the roots are allowed to swap places, and that's what occurs in my fourth solution, as Willie Wong pointed out: one root squared yields the other and vice versa. As regards "cutting the $x$ axis", note that the fourth solution is complex, so you shouldn't be considering this over the real numbers.

Comment: Oh, so in the context of real solutions, it means the equations whose graphs remain unchanged, does it? And for complex roots, can I think of it to mean those equations whose set of roots, when represented on the argand plane(each individually change, but) all together look identical after a rotation through double the angle they were initially inclined to the real axis with?

Comment: @joriki: please respond.

Answer (score 12):

How about just writing: $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=(x-\alpha^2)(x-\beta^2)$, so either $\alpha = \alpha^2$ and $\beta=\beta^2$ or $\alpha=\beta^2$ and $\beta=\alpha^2$.

If $\alpha=\alpha^2$, then $\alpha=0\text{ or }1$.  Similarly, $\beta=0\text{ or } 1$.  So there are three such equations (because $(\alpha,\beta)=(0,1)$ and $(\alpha,\beta)=(1,0)$ yield the same quadratic.)

On the other hand, if $\alpha = \beta^2$ and $\beta=\alpha^2$, then $\alpha^4=\alpha$. If $\alpha=0\text{ or } 1$, then $\beta=\alpha$ and we already covered those quadratics above.  So assume $\alpha\neq 0,1$.  Then $0=\alpha^2+\alpha +1 = \frac{\alpha^4-\alpha}{\alpha^2-\alpha}$.  But then, $\beta=\alpha^2$ is also a root of $x^2+x+1$, so that's one last quadratic.  ($\beta = \alpha^2 = -(\alpha+1)$ so $\beta^2 + \beta + 1 = \alpha^2+2\alpha+1 - (\alpha+1) + 1 = \alpha^2 + \alpha +1 = 0$.)

So you get four quadratics, $x^2$, $x^2-x$, $x^2-2x+1$, and $x^2+x+1$.

So the total is $4$.